# Difference in behavior when hooking a library function via LD_PRELOAD on Ubuntu and CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, c, hook

There is a hook function *socketHook.c* that intercepts *socket()* calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
    printf("socket() has been intercepted!\n");
    return 0;
}
gcc -c -fPIC socketHook.c
gcc -shared -o socketHook.so socketHook.o
```

And a simple program *getpwuid.c* (1) that just invokes the [getpwuid()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3p.html) function:

```
#include <pwd.h>

int main()
{
    getpwuid(0);
    return 0;
}
gcc getpwuid.c -o getpwuid
```

*getpwuid()* internally makes a *socket()* call.
On CentOS:

```
$ strace -e trace=socket ./getpwuid
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
```

On Ubuntu:

```
$ strace -e trace=socket ./getpwuid
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
```

When running (1), *socket()* is intercepted on CentOS, but not on Ubuntu.

**CentOS.** *printf()* from *socketHook.c* is present:

```
$ uname -a
Linux centos-stream 4.18.0-301.1.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 13 16:24:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/socketHook.so ./getpwuid
socket() has been intercepted!
```

**Ubuntu**(Xubuntu 20.04). *printf()* from *socketHook.c* is NOT present:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ibse-VirtualBox 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/socketHook.so ./getpwuid
$
```

So my question is:

1. What does it depend on? I think this is affected by the fact that *socket()* is not called directly from the executable, but from getpwuid(), which in turn is called, if I understand correctly, from libc.so
2. How to achieve the same behavior in CentOS as in Ubuntu? I don't want intercept indirect calls from libc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398366/difference-in-behavior-when-hooking-a-library-function-via-ld-preload-on-ubuntu/67593313#67593313